# Media Queries and Sharepoint Online

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm running into an issue where my media queries are not being rendered by Sharepoint Online.
Here is a list of whats been changed/not changed;

-No customer master page

-Sharepoint is pointed towards the correct CSS file

-Other changes are rendered, but not media queries

-Can't use bootstrap or any custom master page edits (client request)

I'm not sure whats going on.  Here is a snippet of my code.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1200px)
{
/*Nav*/
#DeltaTopNavigation{
margin-left:15%;
}
}
```

I'm using this query because the left nav is hidden and replaced with this custom one.  Even when using em instead of pixels it won't render.

Is there a better solution to make Sharepoint more responsive?

Edit: After some time I've added in the meta tag.  Even though the tag is in place, the media queries don't respond.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: why at close there are two Curly Brackets I think it should be one

Comment: @CY5 Because it's a media query and that's the way they are written.

Comment: @CY5 there **should** be two; one set for the opening of the `@media` rule and the second for the *contained* `id` rule

Comment: @Paulie_D Oops my bad actually #DeltaTopNavigation is in grey(unhighlighted) so i thought its commented thats why i was pointing that bracket should be close

Answer (score -1):

It's possible you're missing a [meta viewport tag](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972)? Media queries won't work without it.

Comment: I thought media queries could be used without the viewport tag? Or maybe I've gotten lazy and used to that viewport tag always being there. Let me see if I can add the tag without touching the master page.